# Creating flex box tabs which auto resize using css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate tabs as seen on a browsers, which auto resize according to the browser width
so far this is my progress

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 35%;
  height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  flex:0;
}

.rest {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="item">item 1</button>
  <button class="item">item 2</button>
  <button class="item">item 3</button>
  <span class="rest"></span>
</div>
```

I searched for solutions online and oddly there were none involving `flexbox` using only pure css.
so is there any way to create this using pure css and flex box?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for,
turns out it was simpler than I thought
all I had to use was a combination of `overflow` and `text-overflow`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 35%;
  height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.item {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="item">item 1</button>
  <button class="item">item 2</button>
  <button class="item">item 3</button>
</div>
```

This also works when resized!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replicate tabs as seen in browsers you may want to try this.

Remove you `span.rest` and then change your code to this.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 35%;
  height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  flex:1;
  max-width: 100px
}
```

`flex:1` will make them take up the available space but your max-width will mean they don't go bigger than they should.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `width: 100%` to your item. It will resize with browser width. Also you can put max width to your container if you don't want your container to go beyond particular width. Take a look at below example.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 35%;
  height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.rest {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="item">item 1</button>
  <button class="item">item 2</button>
  <button class="item">item 3</button>
  <span class="rest"></span>
</div>
```